# 'None' in python output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started learning python in the weekend and whenever I ask for the user input, after what's inside the print there's always a `None` in the output.

code:

```
    print('start - to start the car')
    print('stop - to stop the car')
    print('quit - to exit')
    print('help - to display this menu')
    
    contador = 1
    while contador == contador:
        user_input = input(print('> '))
        user_input.upper()
        if user_input == 'HELP':
            print('start - to start the car')
            print('stop - to stop the car')
            print('quit - to exit')
            print('help - to display this menu')
        elif user_input == 'START':
            print('Car started... Ready to go!!')
        elif user_input == 'STOP':
            print('Car stopped!')
        elif user_input == 'QUIT':
            break
        else:
            print('Command not identified!')
```

output:

```
start - to start the car
stop - to stop the car
quit - to exit
help - to display this menu
>
None
```

Comment: Please post text as text, not as an image of text.

Comment: I think you are indented to write `input('>')` instead of `input(print('> '))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input(print('> '))` displays `None` because `print()` returns `None`. Just do `input('> ')`, which will print the correct thing.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the 8th line

```
user_input = input('> ')
```

You don't need to write print
the input accepts the string which is to be shown while taking the input.